# HELP! civiCRM Administration Area Not Showing! [Joomla 3.6.5] [civicrm 4.7.16]

Tags: admin

I'm using CiviCRM version 4.7.17 on Joomla version 3.65. I changed my civicrm resource URL hoping it would load the civicrm.css file but instead I can no longer access my administration area. Please see phone of what I am receiving when I try to access the civiCRM component. How do I get back to the system settings area so I can change it back?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could try to go the page directly

www.yoursite.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/url&reset=1

If you have sql access you could change them back.  They are stored in civicrm_settings

```
SELECT name, value FROM civicrm_setting WHERE group_name = "URL Preferences"
```

You'll see the url between quotes in the value field.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that worked! I was also able to change the resource URL to it's correct absolute path.

Comment: You're most welcome.  Which method did you end up using?

Comment: I used the first option: www.yoursite.org/administrator/?option=com_civicrm&task=civicrm/admin/setting/url&reset=1